# Web application to download file, edit and reupload automatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I need to create an ASP.NET (or ASP.NET MVC) application which acts as repository for files of any type, and allows you to transparently download, edit and reupload files.

Precisely, the usage is the following:

1. you click "download and edit" on a file in the repository;
2. the file is downloaded via the browser on your machine;
3. the associated file editor (e.g. notepad) automatically starts on that file;
4. you then edit the file.
5. when you close the editor, (or when you press CTRL+s in the editor) the file is automatically re-uploaded to the server.

Is it possible to do that in a browser application (without using Silverlight)? If so, how can the browser "know" the local file has been changed and initiate an upload? Thank you

Comment: Interesting - don't know about a _browser_ being able to spawn some _other_ application on the machine (that's not some plugin), but if were to map this to something like `StackEdit` (or Google Docs, Sheets, etc) where the editing is _in the browser_ (not some other app), and then syncing to some cloud drive and/or saving (downloading) to disk...then yes, it's possible. How? Looks like a lot of exciting/challenging work :)